# Can I make a certain function disabled/skipped throughout the whole PHP script?

Tags: php

I want to debug how much time is `file_exists()` taking up on my site. To debug this, I'd like to disable all instances of `file_exists()`, temporarily, to try how fast the site generates without it.

Is there any easy way to do this? I'm using PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: not how i would do it but, you can use 'disable_functions' in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [disable functions](http://php.net/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in PHP, but that does exactly, what it suggests: It disables the function completely. What you are looking for is simply not possible, because if you "disable" a function, but don't want the script to fail, the function must return something useful. How should PHP return for every builtin- and userspace-function? Especially because PHP can't know, which is the correct value in *every* context: In some cases `file_exists()` should return `true`, in some `false` to make the script work. It will get (obviously) extremely complex, when arrays and objects come into play.

Another approach is to overlay the function with a custom one: PHP searches for unqualified function names in the current namespace first and only after that uses the global one. This means you can create functions named `file_exists()` in each and every namespace.

But my final recommendation: Don't hack in your code for debugging and profiling. **Use a debugger and a profiler** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a uniqe function, and call it instead of `file_exists()` for example:

```
<?php
function call_file_exists($file) {
$debug = true;
if($debug) {
$_SESSION["count"]++; //count all event when file_exist called
return false;
} else { //if no debug, normal function call and return the result
return file_exists($file);
}
}
?>
```

So, if you print `$_SESSION["count"];` it will be display the number of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Install [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), run a [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), see how long all `file_exists` calls take (or any other function), how often they're called, and more.